# Is sane available for using scanner on RHEL 8.5 (Oopta)?

Tags: linux, rhel, scanner, sane

I have installed RHEL 8.5 on a system and want to use scanner with a Java application using SANE. In previous versions of RHEL 7.*x* we use SANE ports for local scanners available on localhost (127.0.0.1). But in RHEL 8.5 we are unable to use SANE. Anyhow we can use scanner with the `iscan` command. But I can't find out how to enable SANE or `iscan` to use a scanner with a Java application.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you were using `saned`; in RHEL 8.5, you need to install `sane-backends-daemon`. The daemon is socket-activated on port 6566.

Comment: I have installed 'sane-backends-daemon' but when i try to run it like 'sudo sane -d' it returns error address is already in use while 6566 only started listening after i run  sudo sane -d

Comment: You’re not supposed to start the daemon manually, it should start on its own when an application connects to port 6566. It may be necessary to enable the service; I can’t check right now.

Comment: When i try to  run my application it gives me error of connection refused.